# The left and right side of an orientation in complex

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The definition of the right side of an orientation $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ is 
$$\{z: Im(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)>0\}.$$

Why is it defined this way?

Note: $(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)=\frac{(z-z_2)(z_1-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_1-z_2)}.$

Comment: If you take the circle passing through $z_1,z_2,z_3$, and traverse it so that these points are passed in that order, you have a concept of left and right of the circle. The circle is just the set of points where $(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)$ is real or $\infty$, the left is the region where the cross ratio lies in the upper half plane, and the right the region where the cross ratio lies in the lower half plane. In short, it is defined thus because it matches our expectations when we look at parametrised circles, and it's a rigorous definition, unlike the hand-waving above.

Comment: How can we show that "the left is the region where the cross ratio lies in the upper half plane"? @DanielFischer

Comment: The map $z \mapsto (z,z_1,z_2,z_3)$ is a Möbius transformation, so an automorphism of the Riemann sphere. It maps the circle passing through $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$, so it maps the two regions determined by the circle to the upper resp. lower half plane. To find which region is mapped to which half plane, compute the image of one point not on the circle.

Comment: I actually tried to prove by simple way. But I could not figure out how the relation between the cross ratio and $z$ from both sides looks like. 

Thank you so much. I will try to make understand it. @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer

There is a theorem that says "Any Mobius transformation maps the right side to the right side and the left side to the left." 

The reason you gave me is kind of using this theorem. But without this theorem, can we prove that if $z$ is on the right, $Im(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)>0$?